# Unable to Find ID of a control (ContentPlace holder) of a webbrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webbrowser-control

I'm working on a Automation where in i need to problematically click a control. Hyperlink. When I tried accessing the control using Document.getelementbyid I'm not able to find it. I searched google it could be the control id changes dynamically

Below is the html source

```
<li>
                        <a id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder_aDocSearchDynamic" href="dynamic.aspx" target="content">Dynamic Doc Search</a></li>
```

When I search using the id of the above

```
    var DynSearch = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder_aDocSearchDynamic");
                if (DynSearch != null)
                    DynSearch.InvokeMember("click");
```

It is returning NULL.

I changed it after search in stakeoverflow.

```
    var DynSearch = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("<%=aDocSearchDynamic.ClientID%>");
```

Still returning NULL.

Please help me out

I'm using Webbrowser control of .NET windows application

Comment: webbrowser1 control of WindowsForm in .NET

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. You can try with `document.getElementById('...')`.

Comment: I'm not searching in Javascript. It is in C# as you can see